# Loop through JSON keys to add Google Maps data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-maps

I found a lot of similar questions to this but none were useful for my particular problem. Basically, I have an AJAX call that fetches a dictionary of users along with their latitude and longitude.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_userInfo',
  function(data) {
    var userinfo = $("#userinfo").text(data.userinfo);
  });
})
```

This returns something like the following JSON:

```
{
  "userinfo": {
    "bob": [
      40.089158, 
      -88.239035, 
      "at home", 
      null, 
    ], 
    "sarah": [
      40.486545, 
      -89.00478, 
      "at work", 
      null, 
    ], 
    "michael": [
     40.089018, 
     -88.239361, 
     "in class", 
     null, 
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know what the key names will be, so I'm not sure how to place the markers. To simply plot the points, I just need the first value (latitude) and the second value (longitude). I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var data = [
   for (var i = 0; i < data.userinfo.length; i++){
     new google.maps.LatLng(data.userinfo[i].[0], data.userinfo[i].[1]),
   }
];

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: data,
    radius: 20
});
```

It doesn't recognize `userinfo` as a valid variable name. I'm not familiar with the syntax of AJAX, what am I doing wrong in either my AJAX call or the for loop for my map data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the syntax issue with the `for` inside an array definition, the issue is because `userinfo` is an object so you cannot loop through it as you can with an array.

Instead, you can use `Object.keys` to get the property names, then loop through those like this:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_userInfo', function(data) {
    var locations = [];
    Object.keys(data.userinfo).forEach(function(key) {
      var user = data.userinfo[key];
      locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(user[0], user[1])) 
    });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: locations,
      radius: 20
    });
    heatmap.setMap(map);
  });
})
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but for some reason it doesn't like that second line and says "Reference Error: data is not defined."

Comment: You need to run it within the function you provide for the callback to the AJAX request. I edited the answer to give you the full code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I figured it had something do with where I was running it. Edited for some minor fixes.

Comment: Just wondering if you could help me with this also: I'm trying to add an infowindow that displays the user's name (aka the key). What's the right way to access that key? Referring to `user[key]` or `user` doesn't work.

Comment: Within the `forEach` loop, that's in the `key` variable